# Big files loading fail in some cases

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a little HTML5/Javascript game for the LudumDare contest and some players reported me an issue concerning asset loading on browsers like Firefox or Safari.
(especially big assets like musics (~600kb each)).

The game is hosted here:

[dl.dropbox.com/u/4936312/LD24/index.htm](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4936312/LD24/index.htm)

(So that you can test if you see a black screen OR the game starting, meaning respectively asset loading fail and success).

The loader script is over here:

https://github.com/cboissie/LD24-Evolution/blob/master/script/ResourceManager.js
(ResourceManager calls ResourceLoader which calls File)

If you get a look to a web developer console, you can see that when it fails, at least one of the response to a GET request failed. (And the GET request was obviously for a file with a 'big' size).

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

EDIT: after checking the web console on Firefox, I can see that some resources have the HTTP1.0 GET 206 status (instead of 200).

EDIT2: This "resources" concerned by the 206 messages are only .wav or .ogg. This means it's related to the HTML5  tag and/or maybe the library I'm using. I will try later to switch to a different library and see if it's working after that. (EDIT3 later this week)

Answer (score 1):

Don't host on dropbox. Dropbox is for sharing files only!

`Dropbox is a free service that lets you bring your photos, docs, and videos anywhere and share them easily.`

Example

If you host your database in dropbox you will get corrupted tables etc. https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=32069

Comment: I don't know if it'll make a difference. A lots of people are hosting small flash/html apps without any concerns. 
Also, I uploaded my project on a friend's server and it's even worse. (but it's a home server, not a professional one).

Comment: `A lots of people are hosting small flash/html apps without any concerns.` Then i'm sure those flash/html apps aren't be used by multiple users at the same time or these apps don't save any data. Still this is not the way to use Dropbox